# Mongodb $inc embedded value syntax

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, database

I'm trying to increment a field in my mongodb document using the $inc operator. The field I am trying to increment is a sub-property of my document's count field, e.g.:

```
mydoc: {
    count: {
        schedules: 0
    }
}
```

When I try this:

```
> db.mydocs.update({ _id: new ObjectId('4db5c2f3dc73c5afdaffd636') }, { $inc: { count.schedules: 1 } }, { upsert: true, safe: true }, null);
```

from my mongo shell, I get this error message:

```
Mon Apr 25 11:59:05 SyntaxError: missing : after property id (shell):1
```

I've tried several syntax variations with similar results. Do I need to take a different approach to this? I've verified my document exists and has a count.schedules field that is set to 0.

I can directly set the value using a command like this:

```
 db.mydocs.update({ _id: new ObjectId('4db5c2f3dc73c5afdaffd636') }, { $set: { count: {  schedules:1 } } }, null, null);
```

But if I try that syntax for the $inc operation, I get this error:

```
Modifier $inc allowed for numbers only
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can do a `$inc` only on numbers. Here is how I tried to reproduce your problem, you can notice I've used proper quotes, which is the reason you are seeing the `missing : after property id(shell):1` error.

```
> db.schedules.save({"mydoc": { "count": { "schedules": 0}}});                                                                                                     
> db.schedules.find();                                         
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4db5cf199e631c2a52a7c643"), "mydoc" : { "count" : { "schedules" : 0 } } }
> db.schedules.update({ _id: new ObjectId("4db5cf199e631c2a52a7c643") }, { $inc: { "mydoc.count.schedules": 1 } }, { upsert: true, safe: true }, null);
> db.schedules.find();                                                                                                                                  
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4db5cf199e631c2a52a7c643"), "mydoc" : { "count" : { "schedules" : 1 } } }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Perfect, Thanks! I need to get in the habit of quoting those.

Answer (score 3):

I think this may be a simple fix. Try putting quotes around `count.schedules` like so:

```
db.mydocs.update({ _id: new ObjectId('4db5c2f3dc73c5afdaffd636') }, { $inc: { 'count.schedules': 1 } }, { upsert: true, safe: true }, null);
```

Comment: Thanks! I gave the credit to lobster1234 since he answered first, but appreciate your help!

Comment: I want to update a field value in database below my code. i have a field that is 'productview' this field will manage how may times user see this product but its not working. like auto increment.

Comment: Product.update({_id:req.params.productId},{$inc: {productview: 1}}, { upsert: true, safe: true }, null);