# Mongo Node Syntax for $inc when number is associated with dynamic field name

Tags: node.js, mongodb, time-series

Similar to the question ([Mongodb $inc embedded value syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5782311/mongodb-inc-embedded-value-syntax)) I'm hoping to increment the value of a number that is a subproperty of another property, but in my case the name of the property is dynamically generated. Here is what the document would look like:

```
mydoc {
   month:  ISODate("2014-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
   data {
     '1':1
     '2':1
     '3':5
   }
}
```

The '1', '2' and '3' fields represent days such that the document can keep counts for a particular month with all the days represented in the data element.

If I explicitly name the property during an update, it works but when I build the property name as a string and pass it in, the string variable name is treated as the property name:

```
// Works as expected 

col.update({ ts: monthdate }, { $inc: { 'data.4': 1 }, { 'upsert': true }, callback});

mydoc {
   month:  ISODate("2014-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
   data {
     '4':1
   }
}

// Doesn't work as expected (or rather hoped..) 

var fieldname = 'data' + 4.toString();

col.update({ ts: monthdate }, { $inc: { fieldname: 1 }, { 'upsert': true }, callback});

mydoc {
   month:  ISODate("2014-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
   data {
     fieldname:1
   }
}
```

Is there some way to escape the property name so that the MongoDB node driver knows it should evaluate its contents rather than the variable name itself?

Thanks!

James

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var inc = { $inc: {} },
    num = 4;

inc.$inc[ 'data.' + num ] = 1;  // you don't need toString()

col.update({ ts: monthdate }, inc, { 'upsert': true }, callback});
```

Answer (score 0):

In ES6 it's easier. Just pass dynamic variable in square brackets. Value inside brackets is evaluated as dynamic field name.

```
col.update({ ts: monthdate }, { $inc: {['data.' + num]: 1} }, { 'upsert': true }, callback});
```

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#new_notations_in_ecmascript_2015)